# Setup SAML federation between Azure AD B2C as IdP and Salesforce as SP

Tags: azure, salesforce, azure-ad-b2c, saml-2.0

I am trying to connect Azure AD B2C as IdP for Salesforce. OpenID Connect doesn't work: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G0000005g7jQAA

For OIDC, Salesforce appears to require the UserInfo endpoint which B2C doesn't implement.

I would like to try and use SAML for federation, where B2C is the IdP and Salesforce is the Service Provider. SAML is achievable through custom policies.

**Has anyone succeeded at SAML 2.0 federation between B2C (as the IdP) and Salesforce? If so, could you share your key learnings, such as a redacted SAML.xml policy & B2C App manifest file.**

Great appreciate the help.

Comment: Start here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory-b2c/connect-with-saml-service-providers

Comment: That's the guide I've been referencing but got stuck (getting 404 error with app when I try to run from MS's SAML test app). MS docs could be outdated (see git issue against doc). Also, some areas aren't clear... especially as that guide references a prior guide but these are 2 different use cases (social for the first and SAML for the second). Wanted to see if anyone else had success and there weren't any gotcha with Salesforce.

Comment: There isn’t any gotchas. Can you describe everything you have done and where this 404 is occurring? At what url and when?